# Panning camera?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I find the default camera controls in M2-TW very unpleasant.

Is there a way to pan/strafe camera rather than having to turn it all the time?

Also, is there an option to zoom out more? I tried playing a canyon custom battle and couldn't zoom out camera to eagle's eye view unless viewing a hill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the camera style to RTS Mode under the Gameplay Options on the main menu, then you can pan using the arrow keys or with the mouse at the edge near the bottom of the screen where the UI is.

I'm not sure about zooming out more, but if you unrestrict the camera in the same menu, it might help you see better, although maybe not up, and it will also let you cheat and view the enemies troops.

Comment: Thanks, but using arrow keys just turns the camer for me, instead of panning. :-(

Comment: @Gnudif: Apparently, there is an option, and I changed it and forgot about it. Go to options on the main menu and change the camera style to RTS Mode instead of Total War Mode. You might also want to unrestrict the camera. It'll let you cheat a little by looking at the enemies troops, but it might let you zoom out more, although maybe not up.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your controls to the fps style control which allows you to strafe with the wasd keys and rotate with the q and e keys